# How to repeat a string?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I really can't find a way how to multiply (repeat) strings in *Mathematica*. 
How to write this shorter?

```
{{"0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "3", "3", "3", "6", "6", "6", "6"}, 
 {"01", "1", "10", "102", "01", "1", "10", "102", "01", "1", "10", "102"}}
```

Is it possible to code something like this ?

```
{{4* "0", 4* "3",4* "6"},{3*{"01","1", "10", "102"}}
```

**Edited**

Just to let you know, I've used `{Flatten[{Table["0", {4}], Table["3", {4}], Table["6", {4}]}, 2],  Flatten[{Table[{"01", "1", "10", "102"}, {3}]}, 2]}` to get what I want. I will try other stuff right now.

Comment: How do you multiply strings at all? Any examples in other languages?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP In _Java_ `repeated = new String(new char[n]).replace("\0", s)` where _n_ is the number of times you want to repeat the string and _s_ is the string to repeat.

Comment: The best I can think is to use a combination of `Table` and `Join` but you'd need to have a large number of elements repeated before this becomes more efficient.

Comment: I see. But do you actually want a *list of strings* here, or do you want to *concatenate* n copies of the same string?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP if I understand your question correctly, I want a list of string. This kind of structure `{ {...},{...} }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following structure could be applied to achieve the desired outcome. However, this may not be the best way to carry out the OPs request:

Please see example below:

**Input:**

```
{Flatten[{Table["x", {3}], Table["y", {4}]}, 2]}
```

**Output:**

```
{{"x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y"}}
```

Furthermore, the code can be repeated to reproduce the desired outcome.

**Reference:**

[Table](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)
[Flatten](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html)

Comment: yes, it can work! but still long. Is that the shortest way?

Comment: Flatten should only affect level 1 though, because otherwise it can't be used to repeat lists.

Comment: I think use of Table as the underlying building block is the way forward. However, it's based purely on my current knowledge of Mathematica. There is surely a better way, however the implementation of such would require use of advanced features. I could describe the implementation if anyone more knowledgeable would like to implement it.

Comment: @Pickett I agree, I used Flatten in order to achieve the format of the sub-list, essentially this process would need to be repeated to create next sub-list, depending on its configuration (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 6):

I recommend this solution:

```
data = {"0", "3", "4", "6", {"01", "1", "10", "102"}};
nrOfCopies = {1, 2, 3, 4, 2};
Flatten[MapThread[ConstantArray, {data, nrOfCopies}], 1]

(* Out: {"0", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "6", "6", "6", "6", {"01", "1", "10", 
  "102"}, {"01", "1", "10", "102"}} *)
```

It is possible to get the exact syntax that you ask for, by adding a new definition for the `*` operator, I just don't like it. If you want this *type* of syntax but are open to another symbol other than `*`, then that symbol is of course `s = ConstantArray`, with `Flatten` (or `Join`) appended afterwards.

```
s = ConstantArray;
Flatten[{s[2, 2], s[3, 3]}, 1]
(* Out: {2, 2, 3, 3, 3} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Note that of course none of this requires the elements of the `List`s to be `String`s.

```
repeatList[lst_List, nTimes_Integer] := Join @@ ConstantArray[lst, nTimes]
repeatElements[lst_List, {n_Integer}] := Join @@ Map[ConstantArray[#, n] &, lst]
repeatElements[lst_List, ns : {__Integer}] /; Length@lst == Length@ns := Join @@ MapThread[ConstantArray[#1, #2] &, {lst, ns}]
```

Then

```
repeatList[{"01", "1", "10", "102"}, 3]
(* {"01", "1", "10", "102", "01", "1", "10", "102", "01", "1", "10", "102"} *)
repeatElements[{"0", "3", "6"}, {4}]
(* {"0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "3", "3", "3", "6", "6", "6", "6"} *)
repeatElements[{"0", "3", "6"}, {4, 3, 2}]
(* {"0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "3", "3", "6", "6"} *)
```

Then, if you want short, why not take advantage of a symbol with no built-in meaning?

```
a_Integer⊗b_List := repeatList[b, a]
(a:{__Integer})⊗b_List := repeatElements[b, a]
```

The symbol `⊗` is `CircleTimes` and can be entered quickly in *Mathematica* as <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>+<kbd>*</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. Alternatively, define the functions using the "`FullForm`" as

```
CircleTimes[a_Integer, b_List] := repeatList[b, a]
CircleTimes[a:{__Integer}, b_List] := repeatElements[b, a]
```

Then,

```
{3}⊗{"01", "1", "10", "102"}
(* {"01", "01", "01", "1", "1", "1", "10", "10", "10", "102", "102", "102"} *)
3⊗{"01", "1", "10", "102"}
(* {"01", "1", "10", "102", "01", "1", "10", "102", "01", "1", "10", "102"} *)
```

Comment: I was thinking to define a new function but didn't know how to do that.Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 6):

This is more for fun, than anything else, but here's a recursive solution as short as possible:

```
sj[n_, s_] := Sequence[s, sj[n - 1, s]]; sj[1, s_] := s;
{4~sj~"0", 4~sj~"3", 4~sj~"6"}
```

> ```
> {"0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "3", "3", "3", "6", "6", "6", "6"}
> ```

For the second use case:

```
SetAttributes[sj, SequenceHold]
sj[n_, {s__}] := {sj[n, Sequence@s]}

4~sj~{"1", "2", "3"}
```

> ```
> {"1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"}
> ```

@march was faster on the uptake with `Infix` notation, but I'd like to point out, that if we're in pursuit of brevity, we can do this with `CircleTimes`:

```
n_⊗s_ := s~Sequence~(n-1⊗s); 1⊗s_ := s;
CircleTimes~SetAttributes~SequenceHold;
n_⊗{s__} := {n⊗Sequence@s};
```

"This" meaning to make definitions with infix notation. I've even set the attributes with infix too :-)

```
4⊗{"1","2","3"}
```

will now work as well.

Comment: +1 for both golfing and `Infix` notation. And also a clever solution.

Comment: @march `Infix` is natural as this is sorta' multiplication. I really like the stuff one can do with functions if one uses `Attributes`/recursion/other unconventional stuff instead of complex definitions.

Comment: Yeah agreed. That's why I chose to use one of the built-ins with no meaning so that the solutions could be written with an `Infix` operator.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Could you please explain why `Infix` useful here and what it means here?

Comment: @Maria The normal notation is `f[a, b]`. For example `Times[a, b]`. But for certain functions, we are more accustomed to `Infix` notation: nobody usually writes `Times[a,b]` or `Plus[a,b]`, everyone write `a*b` and `a+b`. `*` and `+` are operators. They're called `Infix` as they stand between the arguments.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Thank you! Here `~` is `Infix`, right?

Comment: @Maria Almost, but with nuance. `f[a,b]` is equivalent to `a~f~b`, but some functions have a special infix form which doesn't require `~`. Like`CircleTimes[a,b] == a~CircleTimes~b == a ⊗ b` or `StringJoin[a, b] == a~StringJoin~b == a <> b`

Comment: So basically `~f~` is infix, not just `~` or `f`. Unless there's also a special symbol, that stands entirely for the infix form, just like `⊗` stands for `~CircleTimes~`, not simply `CircleTimes`.

Comment: @march I expanded on your use of `CircleTimes`, hope you don't mind.

Comment: Oh it's good! I like the brevity.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "`sj[n_, s_] := Sequence@@Table[s,{n}];`" is shorter.

Comment: Sure, but not by much, and then implementing the second use case is harder

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what the question poser seeks in writing "...this shorter."  Nevertheless

```
ToExpression /@ (x = {{"0", "0", "0", "0", "3", "3", "3", "3", "6", "6", 
   "6", "6"}, {"01", "1", "10", "102", "01", "1", "10", "102", "01", 
   "1", "10", "102"}})
```

will convert each string into an expression, which you can multiply as you see fit.

```
4 x[[1]]

3 x[[2]]
```

or

```
Inner[{4,3},x]
```